# how to run npm-cli.js with pm2 in background

Tags: npm, pm2

Because I was unable to run "npm" "start" I found a workaround where you target npm-cli.js directly, but the problem with this is that pm2 opens a cmd window that when closed, terminates the app.

#### Run

`pm2 start pm2.config.js`

#### pm2.config.js

```js
const process = require('node:process')

function conf_www(){

    const { mode, www_host, www_port, api_host } = require('dotenv').config({ path: './.env' }).parsed    

    console.log('[-] pm2 - pm2.config.js - conf_www -', mode, www_host, www_port, api_host)

    return {

        name: 'www',
        cwd: './',
        script: require('os').platform() === 'win32' ? 'C:\\Users\\_\\apps\\node\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npx-cli.js' : '/usr/local/bin/npx',
        args: mode === 'production' ? 'webpack serve' : 'webpack serve --open',
        autorestart: false,
        env: { mode, www_host, www_port, api_host }
    }
}

function conf_srv(){

    const { mode, srv_host, srv_port } = require('dotenv').config({ path: './srv/.env' }).parsed

    console.log('[-] pm2 - pm2.config.js - conf_srv -', mode, srv_host, srv_port)

    return {

        name: 'srv',
        cwd: './srv',
        script: require('os').platform() === 'win32' ? mode === 'production' ? 'C:\\Users\\_\\apps\\node\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js' : 'C:\\Users\\_\\apps\\node\\node_modules\\nodemon\\bin\\nodemon.js' : '/usr/local/bin/npm',
        args: mode === 'production' ? 'start' : undefined,
        autorestart: false,
        env: { mode, srv_host, srv_port }
    }
}

module.exports = { apps : [ conf_www(), conf_srv() ]}
```